# How to set multiple css using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to set multiple css to the jquery component using id. But it is not working. If anyone knows, please help me to find the solution:

My jquery component is like

```
<select-dropdown mode="disabled" id="maindropdown" type="dropdown" value="Option 1,Option 2"></select-dropdown>
```

CSS:

```
select-dropdown[mode^="disabled"], select-dropdown [disabled], select-dropdown[mode^="disabled"]{
pointer-event:none;
color:#ccc;
padding:2px;
}
```

Trying to change this css using jquery like:

```
$("#maindropdown select-dropdown[mode^="disabled"],select-dropdown [disabled], select-dropdown[mode^="disabled"]").css({

pointer-events:auto,
color:#000,
padding:0px;

});
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, check the console. Look at the quotes in the selector, and the syntax higlighting. Also `<select-dropdown>` isn't a valid HTML element, and best practice in jQuery is to use `addClass()`/`removeClass()` instead of using lots of inline `css()`

Comment: Do you want to select the element purely on the Id basis ?

Comment: Spaces in a selector are the same as `.find()` - ie they find matching child elements - so `$("#maindropdown select-dropdown")` will look for a select-dropdown that's the *child* of maindropdown, whereas in your HTML maindropdown is the id of the select-dropdown.  Just use `$("#maindropdown")` to select by id.  As `id=` must be unique within the document, there's no need for any further filtering.  If it's not unique, then make it unique or use a class and update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your selector:

Try this:

```
$("#maindropdown").css({
    pointer-events: auto,
    color: #000,
    padding: 0px;   
});
```

Comment: Though it's not clear *why* they've added all those other filter attempts (with the typos).

Comment: Accept the answer please. Thanks :)